# odoo14 course url change

Tags: python, odoo-14

i am developing a clients requirement where they deal with e-learning platform built in odoo14
When i select a course from website the url is generating like this

```
/slides/gardening-2
```

can it be modified to

```
/slides/gardening
```

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me to solve this.

i already tried in model portion where i change compute_website_url function. now from the model point of view it generates my desired url but did not know what are the changes i have to done in the controller portion

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very knowledgeable about this, but a former colleague of mine is. Maybe you can check it out[E-learning](https://www.elearningtraining.nl/hoe-je-een-digitale-leeromgeving-kunt-laten-ontwerpen-voor-jouw-bedrijf/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).